# 3rd party Add to Calendar dropdown doesn't show in child page

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want an 'add to event' button with a dropdown displaying a couple of options. For this, I use [AddEvent.com](https://www.addevent.com/buttons/add-to-calendar)

This works perfectly well in the `index.html` page but the problem is that the javascript can not reach the child page. (or at least it seems so)

The guide says to add this script in the `head`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://addevent.com/libs/atc/1.6.1/atc.min.js" async defer></script>
```

Then you just place a `div` which looks like the following

```
<div title="Add to Calendar" class="addeventatc">
    Add to Calendar
    <span class="start">12/29/2016 09:00 AM</span>
    <span class="end">12/29/2016 11:00 AM</span>
    <span class="timezone">Europe/Amsterdam</span>
    <span class="title">Summary of the event</span>
    <span class="description">Description of the event<br>Example of a new line</span>
    <span class="location">Location of the event</span>
    <span class="organizer">Organizer</span>
    <span class="all_day_event">false</span>
    <span class="date_format">MM/DD/YYYY</span>
 </div>
```

Now like I said, this works in the `index.html` but not in  (f.e.) `page1.html`. I thought the problem might be within the 3rd party's javascript file, but I cannot make sense of the file that is shown when I enter that URL. ("https://addevent.com/libs/atc/1.6.1/atc.min.js")

Plunker to demonstrate my problem: [AddEvent-ng2-Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kqRfCzM2BzuAAD1CV8FZ?p=preview)

Comment: the library seems to wait until the document is loaded. However, any angular page will appear after this event, so the library will fail finding the elements. You need to look how to trigger the search on your own and trigger it in component's `ngOnInit`

Comment: @smnbbrv aah okay so for example inserting the script on my page in the `ngOnInit` will work? Or must it be in the `index.html`'s header?

Comment: nope, it would work only for the first time the user sees this angular page. I would rather check the `AddEvent.com` API. I can't go to see it without registration, but you must be able to find a way to retrigger the library there. So you can leave it in `index.html`

Comment: ty so much, turned out they did have this question before. Just had to call a function... oops

Answer (score 1):

Turns out they have this questions a lot. Like [smnbbrv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1990451/smnbbrv) said, the `script` will only get inserted once, but does not reload. So when a new page is loaded, the script will not execute itself. This way the `div` will never be seen by the javascript.

To make this work, I had do define a variable `declare const addeventatc:any;`

And just simply call `addeventatc.refresh();` in the `constructor`/`ngOnInit` of a page I want to use it on.

*(If you have a `Subscribe to Calendar` instead of `Add to Calendar` you will need `addeventstc` instead of `addeventsatc`).*